# Making movement smoother - JS Canvas Game development

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, game-physics

Im experimenting with ES6 & Canvas for game development. In this example I have an image of a spaceship and I rotate it with right and left arrow keys, and move it forward with upper key. 
If you look at the rotation and the moving forward you see that it's laggy. Is there a way to make it smoother?

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jrBLKRJwxrSisj6PQs0N?p=preview)

The code for 'animation' and movement: (found in plunker as well)

from `engine.js`:

```
let mainLoop = function() {
        clrscr();
        draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }

let draw = function() {
        spaceship.draw(ctx);    
    }

    let keyDownListener = function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 37)
        spaceship.rotateLeft();

        if(e.keyCode == 38)
        spaceship.moveForward(ctx);

    if(e.keyCode == 39)
        spaceship.rotateRight();

    if(e.keyCode == 32)
        createExplosion();
    };

    let clrscr = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle="#415575";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    }
```

from `spaceship.js`:

```
let width = image.width * resizeMultiplier;
  let height = image.height * resizeMultiplier;

  const rotateDelta = 0.37; 
  const forwardDelta = 0.77;

  let draw = function(context) {
    //Save context
    context.save();
    //Translate before rotate
    context.translate(x,y);
    //Rotate on translated 0,0
    context.rotate((angle) * Math.PI/180);
    //Draw rotated image
    context.drawImage(image, -(width/2), -(height/2), width, height);
    //Restore the translated & rotated coords to where we began
    context.restore(); 
  }

  let rotateRight = function() {
    console.log(angle);
    angle = (angle === 360) ? 0 : angle + (rotateDelta *(1000/60));
  }

  let rotateLeft = function() {
    console.log(angle);
    angle = (angle === -360) ? 0 : angle - (rotateDelta *(1000/60));
  }

  let moveForward = function() {
    let dx = Math.sin((angle) * Math.PI/180);
    let dy = - Math.cos((angle) * Math.PI/180);
    x += dx * forwardDelta * (1000/60);
    y += dy * forwardDelta * (1000/60);
    console.log('dx: ',dx,' dy: ',dy);
    //x += forwardDelta * (1000/20);
  }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What you want to do is not manipulate the position and orientation of the ship directly, but instead its velocity and angular momentum, and have these properties manipulate the ship in the main loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for that is that you use dedicated functions for each input:
`spaceship.rotateLeft()` , `spaceship.moveForward()` , `spaceship.rotateRight()`

While this looks very good [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) wise, the result is that every time the `window.onkeydown` handler is invoked, it will interrupt/reset the current execution because the key-handler is not in sync with the frame-function.
The frame-function runs (in theory) at a fixed interval. But the key-handler doesn't follow the same pattern, because that get fired when you press a key. So the two kinda work against each other.
*(Anyone please correct me if I'm wrong, not 100% sure about this.)*

In any case, you can resolve it by moving the key-handler to `spaceship.js`, and in the key-handler set a `boolean` for every key to `true` when you press it, and also add a `onkeyup` handler to set them back to false again.
And in your `draw()` function you call the function that calculates all the movement, right before you draw the new values:

```
  //move
  const rotateDelta = 7; //degrees
  const forwardDelta = 10;
  let key = {up:false, left:false, right:false, fire:false};

//DRAW--------------------
  let draw = function(ctx) {
    move();
    ctx.save();
    ...
  };

//MOVE--------------------
  let move = function() {
    if (key.left) {angle = (angle <= -360)?0: angle-rotateDelta;}
    if (key.right) {angle = (angle >= 360)?0: angle+rotateDelta;}
    if (key.up) {
      x += Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*forwardDelta;
      y += -Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*forwardDelta;
    }
    if (key.fire) {}
  };

//KEY-HANDLER--------------------
  window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {key.left=true;} //LEFT
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {key.up=true;} //UP
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {key.right=true;} //RIGHT
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {key.fire=true;} //SPACEBAR
  };
  window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {key.left=false;} //LEFT
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {key.up=false;} //UP
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {key.right=false;} //RIGHT
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {key.fire=false;} //SPACEBAR
  };
```

- As you can see, I also removed what I thought were unnecessary complications for both distance and rotation (`*(1000/60)` and unnecessary brackets etc). If you do need them you can use them of course, but I wanted to keep the calculations as light as possible to remove any cause for stutter. And `rotateDelta` and `forwardDelta` now have nice round values.
  *In Plunker they are `7` and `10`, in the SO Code Snippet I had to lower them a bit because the ship had to be smaller due to the available space.*
- In the left- and right-key calculations I changed `angle === -360` and `angle === 360` to respectively `angle <= -360` and `angle >= 360`, because your angle could skip over `360` and then the value wouldn't be reset. This way is more secure.
- And the last major thing I changed is adding `width:100%;` and `height:100%` to the `<html>`, so the `<canvas>` properly covers the whole page.
- I made some other changes, mainly for myself to get a good overview of your code. If you like the style, use it, otherwise ignore it.

**And the result is a smooth-sailing space machine:**

```js
Engine = window.Engine || {};

Engine = function() {
  let canvas,ctx, w,h;
  
  //player
  let ssImgPath = "http://i68.tinypic.com/2q87s0i.png";
  let ssSizeRatio = 0.1; //multiplier for original image dimensions
  let spaceship; //player object
  
  let ssImage = new Image();
  ssImage.src = ssImgPath;
  
//INIT--------------------
  let initModule = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w=canvas.width, h=canvas.height;
    
    spaceship = new Spaceship({x:w/2, y:h*0.7, angle:0, canvasW:w, canvasH:h, resizeMultiplier:ssSizeRatio, image:ssImage});
    mainLoop();
  };
  
//FRAME-LOOP--------------------
  let mainLoop = function() {
    clrscr();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
  };
  let clrscr = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(65,85,117)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
  };
  let draw = function() {
    spaceship.draw(ctx);
  };
  
//RETURN--------------------
  return {initModule};
}(); window.onload=Engine.initModule;


/*==============================================================*/
/****************************************************************/
/*==============================================================*/


Spaceship = window.Spaceship || {};

Spaceship = function(options) {
  let {x,y,angle, canvasW,canvasH, resizeMultiplier, image} = options;
  let width = image.width*resizeMultiplier;
  let height = image.height*resizeMultiplier;
  
  //move
  const rotateDelta = 7; //degrees
  const forwardDelta = 5;
  let key = {up:false, left:false, right:false, fire:false};
  
//DRAW--------------------
  let draw = function(ctx) {
    move();
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.rotate((angle) * Math.PI / 180); //player rotation
    ctx.drawImage(image, -width/2, -height/2, width,height);
    ctx.restore();
  };
  
//MOVE--------------------
  let move = function() {
    if (key.left) {angle = (angle <= -360)?0: angle-rotateDelta;}
    if (key.right) {angle = (angle >= 360)?0: angle+rotateDelta;}
    if (key.up) {
      x += Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*forwardDelta;
      y += -Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*forwardDelta;
    }
    if (key.fire) {console.log("pew");}
  };
  
//KEY-HANDLER--------------------
  window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {key.left=true;} //LEFT
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {key.up=true;} //UP
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {key.right=true;} //RIGHT
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {key.fire=true;} //SPACEBAR
  };
  window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {key.left=false;} //LEFT
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {key.up=false;} //UP
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {key.right=false;} //RIGHT
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {key.fire=false;} //SPACEBAR
  };
  
//RETURN--------------------
  return {draw};
};
```

```css
html, body {width:100%; height:99%; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Asteroids</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="asteroids.css">
    <script src="engine.js"></script>
    <script src="spaceship.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

***plunker: [https://plnkr.co/edit/nKAyweLV4d0hmmIRzxG4?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/nKAyweLV4d0hmmIRzxG4?p=preview_)***

Comment: funky answer indeed :D thank you very much, let me get you a beer <3